# BackgroundWorker : Passing info from UI thread to Background Worker thread after progressChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asp.net-core-mvc, backgroundworker

I am preparing a WPF application, which starts a HTTP Server on button click,
HTTP Server is a Background Worker:

Code:

> DoWork Event which starts the HTTP server:

```
 private void WebAPI_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            string arg = (string)e.Argument;
            WebAPI.Http_Server.InitHttpServer(bw,e);
        }
```

> HTTP Server code: When an endpoint is being hit on the server, report progress event is being triggered.

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("/XYZ")]
    public virtual IActionResult GetXYZ()
    {

       //do something

        SenderObject so = new SenderObject();
        so.Path = req.Path.Value;
        so.Query = req.QueryString.Value;
        so.ContentType = req.ContentType;

        Http_Server.bw.ReportProgress(1, so);
        // want value of variable "response_for_HTTP" here 

        return StatusCode(so.response_for_HTTP); 
        // return "response_for_HTTP" as status code

    }
```

> Progress Changed Event: This event gets information passed from HTTP server, set the status for HTTP response.

```
private void WebAPI_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            WebAPI.SenderObject so = (WebAPI.SenderObject)e.UserState;
            Request = so.Path;

            //get value for response_for_HTTP
            so.response_for_HTTP = 500;

            //want response_for_HTTP returned to HTTP requester

    }
```

I want to return the status ['response_for_HTTP'] being set in WebAPI_ProgressChanged event delegate,
 to be returned to HTTP server ['place from where event is triggered'].

even after setting response_for_HTTP to 500, I get the response status to be 0.

Comment: If I do Thread.sleep() in action method after - Http_Server.bw.ReportProgress(1, so);

I get the response and works fine.

Comment: @KevinGosse: I am reading about dispatcher now, but trying to make this work too.

Comment: @user6144226 : exactly! the background thread is getting finished earlier. 
If I make it wait until some response is being set, it works. But, not a good way I guess, something like:

 Http_Server.bw.ReportProgress(1, so);

            while (so.Response != 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            return new ObjectResult(so.Response);

Comment: @XYZ this entire flow is quite confusing. You fire a progress event from your action method to pass its value back to itself? I also find the idea of "progress" for  http request wierd, Aren't those just a pair of send & response? Shouldn't you start your HTTP server and treat every request/response as a single async task/backgroud worker run?

Comment: @user6144226: 
> first, the SenderObject has HTTP request details and is being sent to WPF. Where User chooses an HTTP response from UI and that response is set in the response property of SenderObject and is eventually returned as HTTP Response.
> second, the architecture is so because this is just a piece of a big picture. The application has to be started from WPF.